# sh: 1: ruby: not found when i am executing ruby from browser

Tags: ruby, codeigniter, nginx

I am creating a PHP website which have to execute a ruby command from terminal for that i am using :-
1)

```
$output = shell_exec('ruby emailConverter.rb 2>&1');
var_dump($output);
```

This throws the error

```
string(23) "sh: 1: ruby: not found"
```

or
2)

```
exec("ruby emailConverter.rb", $output, $return);
var_dump($output);
```

**UPDATE**

AFTER doing this as @psal  suggested

```
$path = '/home/vishal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby'
$output = shell_exec($path.' emailConverter.rb 2>&1');
var_dump($output);
```

getting this error

```
 string(308) "/home/vishal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require: cannot load such file -- premailer (LoadError)
from /home/vishal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
from emailConverter.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

but when i execute this any of the above command(1 and 2) directly from terminal, it works fine...

what is the problem with that?
Any help?

Comment: `ruby` might not be on the `PATH` of whatever is running your PHP. What's the output of `shell_exec('echo $PATH')`? You could try using the full path to the ruby binary - discover this by using `which ruby` and then calling that file directly.

Comment: this is the reply string(61) "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
"

Comment: How about creating a microservice using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) and communicating to it via JSON?

Comment: @MarkThomas i don't have any idea about this, actually i am new in ruby

Comment: If you're not new to programming or the web, you should be able to pick it up very quickly. It's a much cleaner architecture than integration via command line execution.

Comment: Yes i am not new in programming, thats why i am getting the problems. have a look on [Premailer](https://github.com/premailer/premailer) script , can i run this script via Sinatra

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
I added

`#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.4.1/ruby`

on top of the ruby script file.
ie:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.4.1/ruby
require 'jwt'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As @simonwo said, this error happend because `Ruby` is not in your `PATH`. Find the `ruby` binary using `which` then add it to your script. Usually it's in `/usr/bin/`.

Example on Ubuntu :

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Once you have the path, add it to your `shell_exec` :

```
$rubyBin = '/usr/bin/ruby';
shell_exec("$rubyBin emailConverter.rb 2>&1");
// or
exec("$rubyBin emailConverter.rb", $output, $return);
```

Comment: which ruby says "/home/vishal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby"

Comment: then just add this path to the `$rubyBin` variable and concat the variable in your `shell_exec`. Read my example code...

Comment: okay when i do this now error is  "/home/vishal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- premailer (LoadError)
 from /home/vishal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from emailConverter.rb:4:in `<main>"

Comment: the error said that you need `premailer` lib. You can install it using `gem` : `gem install premailer`